# Quick question about notation and pronunciation of indices: (i+1)st or (i+1)th?

Tags: soft-question, notation

I have a somewhat silly question: What are you calling the index after the $i$th index? The $i+1$st or the $i+1$th? How do you pronounce it and how do you write it down?

I like to write $i+1$ in parentheses because otherwise the $i$ and the $1$th look too separate to me. Intuitively I would pronounce it "i-plus-first", but I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: I would say (i+1)th because the suffix `th` is used for any number after 3

Comment: This is a better question for http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. These expressions are very distinctly used by mathematicians and related scientists, so I think that they have more to say about what's normal in this particular case than say a linguist.

Comment: @stackErr: Numbers such as $21$? If so, you speak a rather different dialect of English than I do...

Comment: @Micah Agreed! But you don't say "i plus oneST" or "i plus first". To me "i plus one th" sounds More correct

Comment: The English-language specialists may easily lead one astray. A nonmathematical friend of mine insisted that I should put commas fore and aft about “and only if” in the expression *if and only if*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I'm not a native speaker, I'm pretty sure that my professor reads it as "$i+1$st". Also, I suppose it's a lot easier to pronounce this creature this way.

Comment: I agree, it's even more obvious for $i+2$, I think. Notation is not so clear though.

Answer (score 2):

I am a native speaker, and in class, I always said “i plus oneth”, “i plus two-th”, “i plus three-eth”. And the students always laughed. My impression is that there is no standard or accepted choice between the two.